# Why are my storm topology not acking when i send tuple to ElasticSearch

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm new to using Storm, I've just started a Data Architect training course and it's in this context that I'm facing the problem that brings me to you today.

I'm receiving messages from kakfa via a KafkaSpout named CurrentPriceSpout. So far, everything is working.  Then, in my CurrentPriceBolt, I re-issued a tuple so that my data is written in ElasticSearch using the EsCurrentPriceBolt . The problem is here. I can't write my data into ElasticSearch directly, it is only written when I delete my topology.

Is there a Storm parameter that can force the writing of tuples by retrieving acknowledgments?

I tried by adding the option ".addConfiguration(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 5)", the tuples are well written in ElasticSearch but not acknowledged. So Storm rewrites them indefinitely.

Thanks for your help
Thierry

Comment: killing topology do what i want but i can't continously kill and add topology

killing topology :
1. flush message
2. send acknowledgements

is a storm command or a storm options that do the same things that killing topology

Comment: Have you considered just using Kafka Connect? It's easier than what you're doing here https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html

Comment: If I had a choice, I could have done that, yes!

But this is a project evaluating the training achievements that imposes the workflow **kafka --> storm --> elasticsearch** on me.

Comment: Understood. Good luck :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer to my problem.
The main problem was that ES is not designed to ingest as little data as is generated in a study project. ES writes, by default, data in batches of 1000 entries. With this project, I generate one data every 30 seconds, or a batch of 1000 every 500 minutes (or 8h20).

so I reviewed in detail the configuration of my topology and played with the following options:

- es.batch.size.entries: 1
- es.storm.bolt.flush.entries.size: 1
- topology.producer.batch.size: 1
- topology.transfer.batch.size: 1

And now it goes like this:

```
...
...

public class App 
{
    ...    
    ...    

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException
    {
        ...
        ...

        StormTopology topology  = topologyBuilder.createTopology();                 // je crée ma topologie Storm
        String topologyName     = properties.getProperty("storm.topology.name");    // je nomme ma topologie
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, getTopologyConfig(properties), topology);               // je démarre ma topologie sur mon cluster storm
        System.out.println( "Topology on remote cluster : Started!" );              
    }


    private static Config getTopologyConfig(Properties properties)
    {
        Config stormConfig = new Config();
        stormConfig.put("topology.workers",                 Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("topology.workers")));
        stormConfig.put("topology.enable.message.timeouts", Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty("topology.enable.message.timeouts")));
        stormConfig.put("topology.message.timeout.secs",    Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("topology.message.timeout.secs")));
        stormConfig.put("topology.transfer.batch.size",     Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("topology.transfer.batch.size")));
        stormConfig.put("topology.producer.batch.size",     Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("topology.producer.batch.size")));      
        return stormConfig;
    }

    ...    
    ...    
    ...    
}
```

And now it works!!!